# Tailwind CSS: Styling Dynamically Created HTML

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, auto-generate

Any one figure out a good way to style auto-generated HTML code with Tailwind CSS?

Example: Using a library like `Marked` to convert `Markdown` into `HTML`, which would then be injected into the page.

The key here, is that you do not know the structure of the auto-generated HTML as the markdown could be in any format created by the author.

Comment: Maybe you looking for [tailwind/typography](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin) plugin?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka thanks for the lead. This may just be the answer to my question. Digging in now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install @tailwindcss/typography
```

configure tailwind.config.js plugins:

```
plugins: [
    require("@tailwindcss/typography")
  ],
```

use it in component with a special className

```
  <article className="prose lg:prose-xl">
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: dynamicContentHere }} />
      </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you could do is like style all elements of a type adding tailwind classes via javascript like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('span').classList.add('text-sm text-gray-500 py-1');
```

etc